# React Native libhermes.so Android

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, package

I try to launch my app but she stop instantly on my phone (or emulator).
I recently update React Native to 0.60.5, and now this appear on Android Studio :

```
2019-08-28 17:15:04.204 2307-2389/com.test E/SoLoader: couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes.so

--------- beginning of crash
2019-08-28 17:15:04.205 2307-2389/com.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: create_react_context
    Process: com.test, PID: 2307
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes.so
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:738)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:591)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:529)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:484)
        at com.facebook.hermes.reactexecutor.HermesExecutor.<clinit>(HermesExecutor.java:20)
        at com.facebook.hermes.reactexecutor.HermesExecutorFactory.create(HermesExecutorFactory.java:27)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:949)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

I work with React Native but I launch Android Studio to find more error. I try a lot of things I found on the web but it still not work.
Someone as a solution ? Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes.so" while enableHermes is false in gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57113794/getting-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-couldnt-find-dso-to-load-libhermes-so)