# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libfbjni.so result: 0

Tags: react-native

I created a new react-native project and added my android native module as a dependency.using official doc https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-setup

When I run this I get the error with following stack trace:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libfbjni.so result: 0
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:825)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:673)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:611)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:559)
        at com.facebook.soloader.NativeLoaderToSoLoaderDelegate.loadLibrary(NativeLoaderToSoLoaderDelegate.java:25)
        at com.facebook.soloader.nativeloader.NativeLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLoader.java:44)
        at com.facebook.jni.HybridData.<clinit>(HybridData.java:34)
        at com.facebook.flipper.android.FlipperThread.run(FlipperThread.java:25)
```

Following is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "albums",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.62.0-rc.5",
    "react-native-my-fancy-library": "../react-native-my-fancy-library/"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.9.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^25.3.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "jest": "^25.3.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.11.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

I have already tried:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61695629/9715339

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57155606/9715339

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25415

But none of these solved my issue.

I am a beginner in react-native. So I don't know what other details files I need to post here. Do let me know if you need any other files.

Comment: Does this issue gone if you remove `react-native-my-fancy-library`?

Comment: @TuanLuong No, I tried removing the library but still getting the error.

Comment: could you try to create completely new project to see whether it works or not?

Comment: Try This :
Reset cache: react-native start --reset-cache
Clean Android: cd android -> ./gradlew clean

Answer (score 47, accepted):

For me the following two solved it (I think it was the latter that did it):

1. Reset cache: `react-native start --reset-cache`
2. Clean Android: `cd android` -> `./gradlew clean`

Comment: For anyone who updated to RN 0.64.2, this solutions works smoothly

Answer (score 3):

for me this is resolved after following below steps
3 steps

1. Up minSdk to 23
2. In gradle.properties add line:
   **android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false;**
3. In your manifest file add line:
   **android:extractNativeLibs=true**;

Comment: It may be enough to set only `jniLibs { useLegacyPackaging true }` in the build.gradle file to package compressed native libraries - see https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin?buildsystem=ndk-build#compress-native-libs-dsl

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem that I solved by updating build.gradle `3.5.2` to `3.5.3` by Android Strudio.

[image]

The image shows the update of the classpath in the dependencies in the build.gradle file in the android folder

Comment: Interesting... Mine worked when i downgraded to  'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'. Thanks for the idea