# React Native Realm app Crash after release build

Tags: reactjs, react-native, realm

I've just setup a clean fresh react-native app (not expo). Made it ready for release and it's working fine, the apk is installing fine on my phone. Realm package install from here https://www.npmjs.com/package/@realm/react. I have setup the working example from the @realm/react. In debug mode, it works fine. After i run npx react-native run-android --variant=release, it builds and installs the release apk , but instant app crash. If i comment out all the realm functions, it works. This is the error:

```
Error: Exception in HostObject::get for prop 'Realm': java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: librealm.so caused by: io.realm.react.util.SSLHelper result: 0, js engine: hermes, stack:
anonymous@1:1140678
loadModuleImplementation@1:36194
guardedLoadModule@1:35743
metroRequire@1:35371
anonymous@1:1140455
loadModuleImplementation@1:36194
guardedLoadModule@1:35743
metroRequire@1:35371
anonymous@1:1138421
loadModuleImplementation@1:36194
guardedLoadModule@1:35743
metroRequire@1:35371
anonymous@1:935016
loadModuleImplementation@1:36194
guardedLoadModule@1:35743
metroRequire@1:35371
anonymous@1:901819
loadModuleImplementation@1:36194
guardedLoadModule@1:35743
metroRequire@1:35371
anonymous@1:42538
loadModuleImplementation@1:36194
guardedLoadModule@1:35700
metroRequire@1:35371
global@1:34955

    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException(Unknown Source:75)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(Unknown Source:148)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(Unknown Source:147)
    at com.facebook.jni.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(Unknown Source:37)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

App.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, Text, TextInput, Pressable} from 'react-native';
import {Realm, createRealmContext} from '@realm/react';
class Task extends Realm.Object {
  _id!: Realm.BSON.ObjectId;
  description!: string;
  isComplete!: boolean;
  createdAt!: Date;

  static generate(description: string) {
    return {
      _id: new Realm.BSON.ObjectId(),
      description,
      createdAt: new Date(),
    };
  }

  static schema = {
    name: 'Task',
    primaryKey: '_id',
    properties: {
      _id: 'objectId',
      description: 'string',
      isComplete: {type: 'bool', default: false},
      createdAt: 'date',
    },
  };
}

const {RealmProvider, useRealm, useQuery} = createRealmContext({
  schema: [Task],
});

export default function AppWrapper() {
  return (
    <RealmProvider>
      <TaskApp />
    </RealmProvider>
  );
}

function TaskApp() {
  const realm = useRealm();
  const tasks = useQuery(Task);
  const [newDescription, setNewDescription] = useState('');
  console.log(tasks);

  return (
    <View>
      <View
        style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center', margin: 10}}>
        <TextInput
          value={newDescription}
          placeholder="Enter new task description"
          onChangeText={setNewDescription}
        />
        <Pressable
          onPress={() => {
            realm.write(() => {
              realm.create('Task', Task.generate(newDescription));
            });
            setNewDescription('');
          }}>
          <Text>➕</Text>
        </Pressable>
      </View>
      <View style={{backgroundColor: 'red', height: 100}}>
        {tasks &&
          tasks.map(i => <Text key={i.createdAt}>{i.description}</Text>)}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "poiTourist",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@realm/react": "^0.4.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.3",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.8.0",
    "realm": "^11.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.2.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.73.7",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

For the past 2 days I've been trying yo get to the source of the problem but no results. With a fresh new install still the same resposne (instant app crash after app build and app install). After some google search I found that realm and hermes was an issue, but not with the last version. Another issue was with react-native-reanimated, but in this fresh project I dont have it. Any solutions? Cheers in advance.

-new fresh rn install,

-followed instructions from official realm docs and rn docs

Comment: did you review [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57036317/react-native-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-couldnt-find-dso-to-load-libherm) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61833727/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-couldnt-find-dso-to-load-libfbjni-so-result-0) or perhaps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43368926/android-reactnative-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerrorcould-find-dso-to-load-libre)

Comment: experience the error today, not sure why it's not documented anywhere on realm docs. I tried many fixes but still end up this message

    -> couldn't find DSO to load: librealm.so caused by: io.realm.react.util.SSLHelper result: 0, js engine: hermes...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So I have manage to fix this. In my case I was not paying attention to all the prerequsitis that realm is providing. The most important https://github.com/realm/realm-js/blob/master/COMPATIBILITY.md Thanks for help